# String matching in scripts

Tags: java, scripting, netweaver

I have a code written in RedwoodScript (Java-like) to reply to all operator messages in a SAP software. I need it to be applied specifically based on string match. As I am new to scripts, I don't have much idea in which language it has been originally written. Please help me with the issue. Thanks.

```
{
   String query = "select OperatorMessage.* from OperatorMessage";
   for (OperatorMessage oMessage : jcsSession.executeObjectQuery(OperatorMessage.TYPE, query))
  {
    //Check the operator message requires a reply
    if (oMessage.getReplyStatus() == ReplyStatus.valueOf("Required"))
    {
      oMessage.setReply("Acknowledge");
      jcsSession.persist();
    }
  }
}
```

My expected output should be, that it should work only with the provided string for string match. Example of such string can be:

"Please check PROCESS_X_215, 4693422521, in XYZ_Queue with status Error"

Comment: what kind of script this code is written with?

Comment: Something known as Redwood script.

Comment: Where do you put it? In what SAP module/tcode? How it is run? What are `operator messages`? Give us more context

Comment: I guess it's RedwoodScript, Java-like, part of SAP CPS by Redwood (SAP Help Portal > SAP Central Process Scheduling by Redwood > [RedwoodScript](https://help.sap.com/docs/search?q=RedwoodScript). Not to be confused with [tag:redwoodjs].